# is return-type signature in function overloading useless?

Tags: typescript

Function overloading in Typescript has a unexpected behavior.

Taking a look at the function overloading [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions-overloads), the return-value signature is part of the function overloading. However, the return type seems to get ignored completely. It is not necessary for Typescript to 'pick' the correct function argument signature and, what bothers me most, it is not used for checking the correct return value.

If the return value of card is changed from a number to a string, Typescript doesn't give any warning.

```
function pickCard(x: {suit: string; card: number; }[]): number;
function pickCard(x: number): {suit: string; card: number; };
function pickCard(x): any {
  // Check to see if we're working with an object/array
  // if so, they gave us the deck and we'll pick the card
  if (typeof x == "object") {
    var pickedCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length);
    return pickedCard;
  }
  // Otherwise just let them pick the card
  else if (typeof x == "number") {
    var pickedSuit = Math.floor(x / 13);
    return { suit: suits[pickedSuit], card: x % 13 }; // <-- change to card: '13'
  }
}
```

My question is: am I interpreting the overload mechanism correctly, so is supplying a return-value signature not necessary or it this a bug?

Comment: Is it at least checked on the caller side? (if you call the first overload, does it croak when you treat the result as something other than number?)

Comment: When pickcard is called with '15' (string) instead of 15 (number) it does complain. If `return pickedCard` is changed to `return 'someString'` it doesn't complain.

Comment: No, I mean, does the caller side get proper type inference for the return value based on choosing the correct overload? According to @SteveFenton's answer, it does. So you have some value in this, even if it does not completely typecheck the implementation of the function, it does check the calling code.

Comment: Yes, @SteveFenton's answer shows correct behavior and I now sort of understand that Typescript is checking, well, the types and not the values.

Comment: I do get what you want. In a perfect world, it should also check the return value of the implementation to match the overload that is being used here. In fact, it should not be necessary to have this whole `if (typeof)` thing, that should go into the separate overloads. After all, your implementation might forget about one case. But that's probably asking too much...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I call your function, I get the following types returned:

```
// a is number
var a = pickCard([{ suit: 'hearts', card: 1 }]);

// b is {suit: string; card: number; }
var b = pickCard(1);
```

This saves me from having to specify it manually:

```
// a is number
var a: number = pickCard([{ suit: 'hearts', card: 1 }]);

// b is {suit: string; card: number; }
var b: {suit: string; card: number; } = pickCard(1);
```

If you were to get them "the wrong way around", you would indeed get errors about the types:

```
// a is number
var a: {suit: string; card: number; } = pickCard([{ suit: 'hearts', card: 1 }]);

// b is {suit: string; card: number; }
var b: number = pickCard(1);
```

So the overload is indeed being picked based on the argument you pass - and the return type is adjusted based on the selected overload.

[View this example on the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=declare%20var%20suits%3A%20any%3B%0A%0Afunction%20pickCard%28x%3A%20%7Bsuit%3A%20string%3B%20card%3A%20number%3B%20%7D[]%29%3A%20number%3B%0Afunction%20pickCard%28x%3A%20number%29%3A%20%7Bsuit%3A%20string%3B%20card%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%3B%0Afunction%20pickCard%28x%29%3A%20any%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Check%20to%20see%20if%20we%27re%20working%20with%20an%20object%2Farray%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20if%20so%2C%20they%20gave%20us%20the%20deck%20and%20we%27ll%20pick%20the%20card%0A%20%20if%20%28typeof%20x%20%3D%3D%20%22object%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20pickedCard%20%3D%20Math.floor%28Math.random%28%29%20*%20x.length%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20pickedCard%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Otherwise%20just%20let%20them%20pick%20the%20card%0A%20%20else%20if%20%28typeof%20x%20%3D%3D%20%22number%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20pickedSuit%20%3D%20Math.floor%28x%20%2F%2013%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20suit%3A%20suits[pickedSuit]%2C%20card%3A%20x%20%25%2013%20%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20change%20to%20card%3A%20%2713%27%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20a%20is%20number%0Avar%20a%3A%20number%20%3D%20pickCard%28[%7B%20suit%3A%20%27hearts%27%2C%20card%3A%201%20%7D]%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20b%20is%20%7Bsuit%3A%20string%3B%20card%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0Avar%20b%3A%20%7Bsuit%3A%20string%3B%20card%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%20%3D%20pickCard%281%29%3B).

Comment: If pickCard is not returning a number but a string (e.g. because of a programming error), Typescript will not complain. (see https://gist.github.com/donnut/7a99207254d23de08ecb for an example). `a` will be `notANumber` instead of 2.

Comment: @donut. but that would be a programming error in the implementation of the function. You do get type-checking of the code that calls  the function. That's something at least.

Comment: You are right. It was foolish of me the forget that Typescript does compile-time type checking and not run-time. It would be nice if programming error like this would be caught as well.

Comment: The problem with overloads is that TypeScript will only check the return type against the implementation signature (which is `any` in the example supplied). The implementation signature needs to have a return type compatible with all specified return types.